# sql- split data table to csv file

Tags: c#, sql, csv

I am working on a C# application which is running continuously and writing data to a SQL database. I am using the express version of SQL Server, so due to that limitation I have to archive the data every 24 hours.

To archive the data I have to split table to 12 CSV files based on a data index. Is there is a way to do that automatically trough the C# or SQL?

Comment: Instead of using Sql Express use MySql or something in the cloud Amazon Aurora.

Comment: why do not store the data directly as csv files?

Comment: this is actually quite easy to do if you were to store the table data and return it into a `DataTable` let me know if you want to see and example and I can post an example for you ..

Answer (score 0):

i am not a C# expert, but i had to do this in the past using PHP, and i assume the logic will be the same for you.
What i did was adding a count variable like `$i=0;` above my while loop. the while loop is the one looping through the SQL results. In that loop i had my counter going +1 `$i=$i+1;` then at the end of the loop `if($i == 1000) {  [C# code for writting in the file]; $i =0;}`
So it will create a new file every 1000 records, and put $i back to zero when done.
You can have another count variable to add to the file name so it does not overwrite the previous one. like `$y=0` before the loop and `$y=$+1` and `file_name = $y.'_file.csv'` within the loop.